# Can IP phones be eavesdropped upon if administrator access is available?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, voip

I am interested in demonstrating an attack to my university's security team on IP phones installed at the university. The IP phone models are [Siemens optipath410](http://www.officephoneshop.com/siemensphones/products/siemens-optipoint-range/25/siemens-optipoint-410-standard/?gclid=CLqaoOuBq70CFU_KtAodRTMA0A).

Basically, using `nmap`, I identified a few IP phones on the network. The IP phone have the following ports open: `https` (443), `telnet` (21) and `ssh` (22). When I visit `https://IP address`, I get the webpage which asks for administrator password. The default password works here.

Now I have full control over all the settings. Is it possible that I can listen to and record conversations? Is it possible to sniff packets on Wireshark and then convert to an audio stream?

Or is possible to perform a man in the middle attack while routing the traffic on my IP and then forwarding it?

This is the main admin page.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is very easy if you know the current sip or voip platform use (and you must know because you can access the admin page of the phone)  and you know how to create a sip or voip relay with asterisk or anyother VOIP gateway.

You could then reconfigure phone so they use your voip gateway and send the packet to the IPBX of your university.

This would be like a man in the middle, the problem you can have here is finding which is the user connection credential to the university VOIP gateway, if there's one.

Comment: i have uploaded the admin page screen shot. can you be a bit more directive according to the settings? Where should I read on voip?

Comment: I can explain you a concept, I will certainly not explain you in details how to listen to conversation when it's that easy to do.

Comment: OK. i am ok with the concept explaination